# IE11 z-index issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index, internet-explorer-11

I have strange layout issue with IE11, the nav on my website seems to be "sitting below" another element. Strange thing is that it works in every browser except for IE11.

Also if you click on "Go to benefits and see why.." in the circular block it takes you to the second section on the site. Nav works from every section except for the landing page.

Link to site here: http://goo.gl/WS1M8l

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks guys.

Comment: "the nav on my website seems to be "sitting below" another element" which element..? can you be more specific?

Comment: .Container is above .Header regarding z-index.

Comment: the z-index for '.header' is set to -1 and container is set to 1. Do you want '.header' to show on top of '.container'? If yes, change the z-index for '.header' to 2

Comment: No, thats not what i'm looking for. I would like someone to explain the z-index issue in IE11 only. It even works in IE8 but not 11. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a lack of understanding utilising the z-index CSS property. See this great article:[from Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) which explains the z-index property and it's many use scenarios.

Note: You should amend your code to ensure cross-browser compatbility, not expect the browser to amend it's behaviour to suit your code.

Comment: Please avoid just linking to other resources, rather, it is recommended that you quote (or even paraphrase) the information and link to the source, so that the information is conserved even if your link becomes defunct.

Comment: will - I respectfully disagree with your answer.  I do agree that you should make sure you have cross-browser compatibility, but it appear IE 11 does not seem to be following the rules associated with z-index.  The article you sent stated that you should make sure to set the position property in order to make z-index work.  I followed this rule to the T, yet the layers are rendering incorrectly.  (btw - I did vote up your answer, because I do think the article is a great explanation.)